# Simple way to setup new Alfresco server with production configuration

Tags: tomcat7, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I have backup of production `Alfresco 4.2 Enterprise` server consisting of:
- database;
- folders `Tomcat7`, `Alfresco` (where `alf_data`, `alfresco-global.properties` and etc).

Currently I'm deploying new standby server with production configuration and planning to make this with minimal efforts - without installing modules, configuring Tomcat, SOLR and etc. The configuration of production and stanby server must be identical.

It can be used for reservation, for example, if primary server will fall. 
In this case just requires to restore repo data (db, content store, indexes) on standby server from relevant production backup.

To setup standby server I'm planning to use these steps:
1) Install OS and Alfresco. Stop `tomcat7` service on new server.
2) Restore production database with different name from the backup.
3) Delete `Alfresco` and `Tomcat7` folders from new installation.
4) Restore production folders `Alfresco` and `Tomcat7` on new server from the backup.
5) Edit main properties in `alfresco-global.properties` like `db.name`, `alfresco.host`, `share.host` and also options in `catalina.sh`.
6) Start `tomcat7` service on new server.

Will these steps corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, basically you are setting up another server by copying the installation and config from your current server. Then, when you need to do a recovery, you are going to recover the database, then you'll recover the content store. Then, you'll start up the server.

The only question I would have is does it make sense to have the backup server sitting there doing nothing. If you have the installation and config backed up, then all you are saving by taking this approach is the time necessary to re-establish the server (assuming you are virtualized, this should be quick) and then recover the installation and config, which should also be quick.

Comment: Thanks, it important moment for me! I did testing and it works. To answer your question, the problem is that until we have not tools for automatically and quick backup/restore virtual machines with linux (only buit-in tools, for example, creating snapshots and cloning machines, but it's not best practice for production). Backup server of Alfresco will allow to reduce the time of recovering if main server will fail (in this case we need only recover database and content store of Alfresco there).